# Do you make a word then give it meaning, or do you think of a meaning and assign a word to it?

Tags: conlang-creation, vocabulary

I wonder which is more effective, creating a list of conwords then giving definitions or, creating a list of definitions then assigning conwords?

Comment: Readers of this question may also be interested in this one: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/1608/142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**meaning** and then words, because every language is built on the needs of the environment in which is based. **List the main words used** in that environment according to the geography and culture you are planning, **then you can start to separate it into groups and assigns common radicals** and all the other word-creation processes.

Answer (score 1):

I have mostly made up conwords when I had a new meaning in mind. Most of the time now I am deriving new words from combinations of existing words. I do occasionally think of a conword that sounds so good that I replace past words or seek out a meaning so that it will become a fairly common usage.

That said, one way or another, I do wind up with conwords I like but don't need yet. I keep a list of them for future use. Importantly for my productivity, I have a counterpart list of English concepts for future use: so that I neither forget them nor randomly divert myself from the task I'm on when I think of them.