How to Construct Phonotactics?
For use in worldbuilding, I am intending to construct some fictional names in a fictional language. I want the phonotactics in those names to be distinct from the more widely-known real-world languages/families (so preferably avoiding or diluting PIE, Sinitic &c. features), but easy to convey in writing to an Indoeuropean audience, and plausible-sounding.
Given those constraints, what are good simple guidelines and principles for coming up with a set of phonotactics for such naming?

PIE phonotactics are pretty strange compared to any modern language I've seen!

The answer here may be of some interest.
https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/how-does-one-go-about-designing-phonotactics-for-a-conlang

First of all, you should familiarise yourself with the common features of Indo-European languages. For a good starter see What are the defining traits of a Euro-centric conlang? and its answers. Unfortunately, we don't have similar questions and answers for other major language families like Sino-Tibetan, Austronesian, Semitic, or Bantu.
The simplest way to deviate from well-trodden paths is by incorporating a restriction, e.g., on word-final sounds or on consonant clusters. Elvish conlangs have some remarkable phonological features here, like the restriction of word-final consonants to coronals (/d/, /t/, /n/, /s/ ...). For more suggestions, see Designing a mildly weird phonology and its answers.
Another device often used by fantasy authors hiatuses, especially the "defining fantasy vowel" /ae/ (Laura Wattenberg), but also a fondness of /ie/ and /ue/.
You can restrict word-initial consonant clusters by adding a prosthetic vowel to them; or you can go in the opposite direction and add consonants to words starting with a vowel, such that all words begin with a consonant or consonant cluster.
